Why if the application is installed in Incremental File System it is smaller than the apk file
When I install an application, in most cases it is smaller than the file downloaded from the play store, I checked these applications in /data/app and it turned out that all applications that use the Incremental File System have this error, if the application uses f2fs, it displays normal (150 mb) otherwise only 32 mb is displayed. It seems that most of the applications installed by the main user from the play store install to the Incremental File System, when I install the same application but first on the second user and then on the main one, then the file system is f2fs


Original post:
The size of the application in the settings is smaller than the one downloaded from the play store and also when leaving and entering the settings the size of the application keeps decreasing, for example in the play store the application weighs 90 mb, we install it, it weighs only 70 mb, we open the settings a few more times and this size drops to only 30 mb. Why does this happen? In my opinion, the size of the application should be rather constant and only the data and temporary memory can change. I'm not 100% sure, but this problem happened to me on Coloros phones and derivatives, e.g. realme ui.
Video
https://imgur.com/a/p4zqHGt
Edit 1
log: https://gist.github.com/432533/e53c8fa441636aa0daec60d3245afef6
the package name of the application I used as an example is com.lastquarterstudios.catsareliquidabp
Information Update:
I found out that the error occurs only when I install the application for the main user (userid 0) from the play store, when I install the application on another user, the size is displayed correctly 150 mb. When I install the apk, xapk, apkm file, the error does not occur. When I install the same application first on the second user, e.g. userid 13 and then install it with play store on the main user, the displayed size of the application is normal. I am not sure, but when I download the application update from the Play Store, the application originally installed on the main user (userid 0) is fixed. I managed to notice the error on 3 phones, on my oppo, realme and my friend's realme, and I determined that the bug probably exists since android 12. Just to clarify, if the translation is not accurate, the error occurs for all installed applications, mostly games, among applications it also happens but less often, I'm not 100% sure.
Log:

Running the same application on 2 different phones
https://gist.github.com/432533/998c09294576d96c408cb951cde808ed
realme
https://gist.github.com/432533/206bca657c4f9adab99512453077df64 oppo
Checking the size of the application that was first installed on the
second user and then on the main user
https://gist.github.com/432533/c20b00fee6eca4a941136c28418b5cb9 (coloros 12)
Installation process from the Play Store on the device with an error
https://gist.github.com/432533/872d7441270f2b2163bacde0a063b410




The app size change is indeed strange. An increasing size would be possible (some apps can download extension data from Google Play after installation) but shrinking? May be a bug in the size calculation? The Play Store download size varies a lot the last time, until now I thought this is related to the fact that updates can be provided as diff to the already installed APK files, but may be the size is also to exact for newly installed apps.

com.lastquarterstudios.catsareliquidabp is an app that two splits: a base.apk of 72.8 MB plus config.arm64_v8a.apk of 17.7 MiB.  Play Store web site mentions a download size of 90 MB matches the sum of the two split APKs. As Android keeps both APK files after installation, the app size can not drop below that value.

In theory yes, but in practice it doesn't work very well. On my old phone, custom rom Android 8.1 works normally 157 MB apks + decompression
